# Problem with accurately detecting user's IP address

Tags: ip

I have an unforeseen problem, namely I made a chat and it works perfectly.
Now I have a problem with the ip address, namely through user registration I take the ip address. In a PHP web application it's done like this:

```
$user_ip = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

The problem arises when I changed the name servers (with cloud flare name servers) the ip I have in the database is not the real ip of the user but the ip behind which the ddous guard is hidden (it was used before cloudflare)...
And when I ban a user, every user who has the same ip will get the ban (ddos guard assigned the ip that way) see screen shot:
(removed link ) (this is just example)...
Now i need the best solution to avoid this problem ,for all users i can maybe manual delete ip adresses and  to save in database last logged ip adress?
But ho w i can to solve this problem for future...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Best solution is not to rely on IP address for identifying your users. Even without your own change, 200 users all accessing your site from the same company network would also all have the same public IP address. Or 2 people in the same house using the same router have the same IP. And then they switch to their 4G mobile connection and it's the same person with a different IP address. Or their ISP changes their IP address, and it's the same people with a different IP. Or they switch to using a VPN sometimes. IP address is pretty much useless for identifying people these days (if it ever was).

Comment: You could perhaps use IP address as _part of_ a strategy for identifying users who need to be banned, but it's certainly not the solution by itself. Now it's not a topic I know all the details of, but banning users on forums etc is a common requirement and I'd be surprised if there aren't blogs, articles, services, plugins etc all available online already for you to research how to implement your overall banning requirement more effectively, and maybe even give a ready-made solution.

Comment: And none of this has anything to do with PHP really either, btw.

Comment: What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: `What do you suggest as an alternative? ` ...Read my second comment again.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure your users are going to thank you for publishing their usernames and email addresses online. You might want to delete that screenshot a.s.a.p. Data protection...privacy...security...spam email...do these words mean anything? At least the IP addresses can't help much to identify them, eh? Even if that's from your test database, they sure look like real emails.

Comment: Yes i understand you that is from my test database from my server ,but i will delete  that screenshot....

Comment: Even if it's from a  test database they look like real email addresses.

Comment: Anyway, you've removed the link from your question but you haven't actually deleted the image from its location. At the time I am writing this the URL still works (and is still visible in the revision history of your question). You need to delete the actual image you uploaded, not just remove a link to it.

Comment: The picture is still there! You didn't delete it.